# Send Facebook messages from a phone without Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Recently, Facebook started to warn me that I won't be able to send and read messages through the mobile web page and I will have to use Facebook Messenger.

Now, when I want to read my messages, I see this:

[image: switch to messenger]

Facebook Messenger doesn't work on my phone, so this means I'm not able to read and send messages through Facebook.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm not sure we can really answer the "Why?" portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I get around it using Android Chrome:

1. Go to m.facebook.com
2. Click on the Chrome menu dropdown on the far right of the address bar
3. Toggle the "Request desktop site" option
4. Now click on the FB messages tab

You may not have the desktop site option depending on your phone. I'm not aware of any other way to do this.

Comment: thanks, actually I just found out this solution myself :D what a coincidence